# Given two projections $E_1$ and $E_2$ with $\deg (E_1) = \deg(E_2)$, prove that $E_1$ and $E_2$ are similar projections.

Tags: linear-algebra, projection, projection-matrices

Given two projections $E_1$ and $E_2$ and $\deg(E_1) = \deg(E_2)$, prove that $E_1$ and $E_2$ are similar projections.
I'm trying to understand how this sentence can be proved, from which direction should I start the proof, is it by analysing the two projections and the way they are constructed, or that there are some properties that I'm missing?
Any hint!

Comment: What is the background ,? Are you deallng with a finite dimensional space ? Is the space equipped with an inner product  orv the problem is purely  algebraic ? Do you assume that the projections are orthogonal ?

Comment: Actually, there is no such given info, but according to the background I'm dealing with I can assume that it's purely algebraic, in addition, I can assume that it's finite-dimensional and that the projections are orthogonal.

Comment: Let $V_i $ be the range of $E_i$ for $ i=1,2.$ Choose a basis $B_i$ in $ E_i$ and complete it to a basis $B_i\cup D_i$ of the entire space. The sets $B_1$ and $B_2$ have the same cardinality as well as the sets $D_1$ and $D_2.$ Let $U$ be a one-to-one mapping from $B_1\cup D_1$ onto $B_2\cup D_2.$ Then $U$ can be extended by linearity to the isomorphism of the entire space and $E_2=UE_1U^{-1}.$ In case the projections are orthogonal the bases constructed on the way  could be chosen orthonormal. In that case $U$ is a unitary operator.

Comment: Instead of "degree", isn't it "range" ?